# Can't align p inside div with margin 0 auto

Tags: css

I don't know what is going on but I can't align a `<p>` inside a `div` with `margin:0 auto;`
I can't understand what is wrong or what i'm missing, this is the code:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>Text that has to be centered</p>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
 .test
  {
     width: 100%; 
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 600px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color: #ececec; 
  }
 .test p
  {
     display:inline-block;
  }
```

With this, the text is moved just a little bit on the center of the div but it's not fully centered

Comment: please check you code module once as you are not using go-choice class in body but using test which has no properties..

Answer (score 0):

```
 .test p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

that's all you need.

If you were centering a block element you would need `margin:auto`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test">
        <p align="center">Text that has to be centered</p>
</div>
```

what exctly you want Please clear your qurestion,
whether you want to align text center/left/right or just change postion of

tag

Comment: also you can use <p style="text-align:right"> directly